# Toggle css on ng-click

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

This is the basic idea of my code:

HTML (jade):

```
#preferencesBox(ng-click="toggleCustom()")
   .glyphicon.glyphicon-heart
```

CSS:

```
#preferencesBox.active{
   color: #d04f37;
}
```

Angular:

```
$scope.check = true;
$scope.toggleCustom = function() {
    $scope.check = $scope.check === false ? true: false;
};
```

I want to add the css `color : #d04f37` when the user clicks the parent `#preferencesBox`. Adding/removing `.active` is the jQuery way. How should my `ng-class` or the rest code look like?

Comment: So change color when the mouse is down and then back when released?

Comment: @oGeez No be permanent until the next click. Like a html checkbox.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use an expression inside `ng-class` that will watch the `check` variable:

```
ng-class="{'active' : check}"
```

When `check` = `true`, add class `active`

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the next example and apply in Jade:

```
<header ng-click="click()" ng-class="{'active': active == true}">Hello</header>
```

Then, in your controller:

```
$scope.click = function(){
    $scope.active = true;
}
```

I'd say this is simple enough to get you started and add logic for toggling into `click()` (it's only an `if`).